# Accordion - Open first tab from a mapped array - React TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, accordion

```
{accordion.map(accordionItem => (
                <AccordionItem
                    key={accordionItem.title}
                    text={accordionItem.text}
                    title={accordionItem.title}
                ></AccordionItem>
            ))}
```

I have an Accordion component that maps over an array of data. I am trying to open just the first tab. There are properties you can add to default expand all or none, but wondering how to do this on the first tab?
Material UI also has customised Accordions but they are focused when all data is in one file and not mapped through an array.

```
<Accordion className={classes.accordion} defaultExpanded={false}>
        <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls='panel1a-content'
            id='panel1a-header'
            style={{
                borderBottom: '2px solid #EBEDF7'
            }}
        >
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>{title}</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
            <Text label={text} className={classes.body} html>
                {text}
            </Text>
        </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 5):

This seem to work for me with MUI v5 to open first item (summary) of the accordion

...

```
          summaries.map((summary, index) => (
            <MuiAccordion
              defaultExpanded={index === 0 ? true : false}                  
              key={summary.id}
            >
```

...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I know what the title of the tabs will be so I was able to do a simple if statement that would open the first tab if the tabs name was as such.

```
const firstTabCheck =
    title === 'Invest some of it' ? (
        <Accordion className={classes.accordion} defaultExpanded={true}>
            <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls='panel1a-content'
                id='panel1a-header'
                style={{
                    borderBottom: '2px solid #EBEDF7'
                }}
            >
                <Typography className={classes.heading}>{title}</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                <Text label={text} className={classes.body} html>
                    {text}
                </Text>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    ) : (
        <Accordion className={classes.accordion} defaultExpanded={false}>
            <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls='panel1a-content'
                id='panel1a-header'
                style={{
                    borderBottom: '2px solid #EBEDF7'
                }}
            >
                <Typography className={classes.heading}>{title}</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                <Text label={text} className={classes.body} html>
                    {text}
                </Text>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    )
return firstTabCheck
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this if anyone wants to reply but this has fixed my issue for the time being.

Answer (score -2):

```
{forms.map((form,index) => {
                return (
                    <Accordion expanded={expanded === `panel_${index}`} onChange={handleChange(`panel_${index}`)}>
                        <AccordionSummary
                            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                            id="panel1bh-header"
                        >
                            {form.status === "pending" && (
                                <Chip
                                    style={{ margin: '0' }}
                                    size="small"
                                    label={form.status}
                                    color="default"
                                    clickable
                                    icon={<HistoryIcon />}
                                />
                            )}
                            {form.status === "approved" && (
                                <Chip
                                    style={{ margin: '0' }}
                                    size="small"
                                    label={form.status}
                                    color="primary"
                                    clickable
                                    icon={<DoneIcon />}
                                />
                            )}
                            {form.status === "rejected" && (
                                <Chip
                                    style={{ margin: '0' }}
                                    size="small"
                                    label={form.status}
                                    color="secondary"
                                    clickable
                                    icon={<ClearIcon />}
                                />
                            )}
                            <Typography className={classes.heading}>{form.typeOfleave}</Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>{moment(form.createdAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</Typography>
                        </AccordionSummary>
                        <AccordionDetails style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                            <div>
                                <Typography gutterBottom className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
                                    Reason : {form.reason}
                                </Typography>
                            </div>
                            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                                <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
                                    From : {moment(form.from).subtract(10, 'days').calendar()}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading} style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}>`enter code here`
                                    To : {moment(form.to).subtract(10, 'days').calendar()}
                                </Typography>
                            </div>
                        </AccordionDetails>
                    </Accordion>
                )
            })}
```

**set expanded state (default state) to '0' because array index is starting from 0**

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('panel_0');

const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
        setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
    };
```